# How to prevent Java XSL transformer from inserting namespace prefixes?

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I am using javax.xml.transform.Transformer and a 1.0 XSL document to convert XML to XML.

One of the XSL templates I am using is to

- copy an entire sub element and all its children
- insert a namespace declaration into the top level node of this sub element
- remove all namespace prefixes from the tags in the sub element

Here is the code for the template:

```
  <xsl:variable name="replacementNamespace" select="'abc.123.xyz'" />

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="newNamespace">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{$replacementNamespace}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="newNamespace" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

Here is what I need:

```
<type xmlns="abc.123.xyz">
  <usr></usr>
  etc...
</type>
```

The output it is creating looks like this:

```
<ns0:type xmlns:ns0="abc.123.xyz">
  <ns1:usr xmlns:ns1="abc.123.xyz"></usr>
  etc...
</type>
```

Comment: Try using `<xsl:element name="{name()}" ...` instead

Comment: Try making your namespaces absolute. This means prefixing them by `http://`.... It may be that Java needs this.

Comment: @xtratic - kinda worked... but now the namespace prefixes from the input are getting copied and I wanted to strip them from the output.

Comment: Maybe `<xsl:element name=":{local-name()}"...` with leading semicolon?

Comment: @Infin8Loop: Yes. This is correct behavior. `name()` does copy `namespace-prefix:element-name` and `local-name()` only copies `element-name`.

Comment: @zx485 ok so how do I only copy the element name without prefixes and prevent java from inserting its own prefixes?

Comment: The answer to that was in my other answer: use `exclude-result-prefixes="..."`. But I cannot guarantee you that this works with Java. It surely does work with XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT 1.0 gives processors complete discretion to use any namespace prefixes they like in the output.

Your code should do what you expect if you run it with an XSLT 2.0 processor: the XSLT 2.0 spec is more prescriptive on the choice of prefixes, and with this construct

```
<xsl:element name="{local-name()}" 
             namespace="{$replacementNamespace}">
```

you are guaranteed to get no prefix.

So try it again with Saxon.